# Flutter delete item from list causing full rebuilt

Tags: flutter, listview, statefulwidget

I actually have a list with a remove button.
Once pressed, it shows a dialog to be sure that we want to delete the item.
Once deleted, i would like that the item disappears from the UI without rebuilding the full list.
I just need that the item concerned be deleted. So it should not do any loading process.

Actually, the list is fully rebuilt. [image]
I was using a statelesswidget, now it is a statefull widget. I thought it would help me..

Source code :

```
class ListGroupsOfUser extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  ListGroupsOfUser({
    required this.emailParameter,
    required this.title,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String emailParameter;

  @override
  _ListItem createState() => _ListItem();
}

class _ListItem extends State<ListGroupsOfUser> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(children: [
        // Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5)),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 8),
          child: Badge(
            toAnimate: true,
            animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
            shape: BadgeShape.square,
            badgeColor: Colors.indigo,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            badgeContent: Text("Utilisateur : " + widget.emailParameter, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
                future: UsersAndGroupsService.fetchGroupsOfUser(widget.emailParameter),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    final result = snapshot.data!;

                    return ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
                      itemCount: result.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                          child: Card(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ListTile(
                                  title: Text(result[index].name),
                                  leading: Icon(Icons.group),
                                  trailing: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.red),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      confirm(context, "Suppression", "Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer le groupe " + result[index].name + " de l'utilisateur ?", result, index);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                }))
      ])));

  _confirmResult(bool isYes, BuildContext context, List<User> result, index) {
    if (isYes) {
      print("HELL YES!");
      print(result.length);
      setState(() {
        result.removeAt(index);
      });

      print(result.length);
      // print(userInputController.text);
      // _write();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } else {
      print("HELL NO!");
      // print(input);

      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }

  confirm(BuildContext context, String title, String subTitle, List<User> result, index) {
    return Dialogs.materialDialog(msgStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16), msg: subTitle, title: title, color: Colors.indigo, context: context, actions: [
      IconsOutlineButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _confirmResult(false, context, result, index);
        },
        text: 'Cancel',
        iconData: Icons.cancel_outlined,
        textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        iconColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      IconsButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _confirmResult(true, context, result, index);
        },
        text: 'Delete',
        iconData: Icons.delete,
        color: Colors.red,
        textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        iconColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Update after answer :

```
late Future<List<User>> result2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    result2 = getUserList();
  }

  Future<List<User>> getUserList() async {
    return await UsersAndGroupsService.fetchGroupsOfUser(widget.emailParameter);
  }

...

child: FutureBuilder(
  future: result2,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    Don't know if updates needed after that
```

Update 2 :

```
List<User> result = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserList();
  }

  getUserList() async {
    result = await UsersAndGroupsService.fetchGroupsOfUser(widget.emailParameter);
  }

...
Expanded(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: result == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
                    itemCount: result.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

result == null : the operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.
And something strange, i go on the page, results are loaded, but if i press back button and i go again on the page, no results are loaded, it's stays empty
-> List? result solved the error message
A Gif to show the problem. The data comes only when i do CTRL+S on VSC xD
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**setState** will rebuild your entire build method so your `FutureBuilder` will reload again that is why it's loading again.

Remove FutureBuilder and call  `UsersAndGroupsService.fetchGroupsOfUser(widget.emailParameter)` in **initState**.

When data will come initialise list and use that list.

**Code:**

```
List<User> result;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
  getUserList();
}

getUserList() async {
  result = await UsersAndGroupsService.fetchGroupsOfUser(widget.emailParameter);
  setState(() {});
}
```

in build method

```
result == null ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Listview()
```

Now you can execute your code with peacefully :)

Comment: True, and he needs to assign Key for his tiles in a list to prevent unwanted behaviour after item deletion.

Comment: @Priyesh Thanks for the response, but i don't arrive to apply it, i tested other things too, but i don't understand how i should modify my FutureBuilder.. I update my post

Comment: I updated with a second edit, i think i understood your answer, but i have a strange behaviour

Comment: @SimonSot For what you said, can you explain why should i do that : `key: new Key(index.toString()),` , what type of unwanted behaviour could i have ?

Comment: @Kévin for example lets say you can select your tiles and change their state (for example you change color to indicate that item is selected). After you delete a tile from a list without a unique Key your state will be shifted, deleted tile will be gone but states from other tiles will shift and you will see in this example highlighted another tile that you did not select.

Comment: @SimonSot Ok i understand thanks ! I updated my post again to show a gif with the problem of display

Comment: @Kévin try to replace `List<User> result = []` on `late List<User> result;`

Comment: @SimonSot I already did it ;) But was not resolving the == null, `List<User>? result;` is resolving the null error

Comment: I finally found the problem, thanks to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60863575/list-not-being-updated-when-list-updated-from-initstate
We have to set this because the widget is already build when the data arrives ! `setState(() {});` I will update your answer (i cannot queue full)
in the getUserList, add at the end : setState(() {});

Comment: Thanks for your help @SimonSot. Keep growing Kévin.